# How to implement a live search in Meteor without text input blurring after every letter?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am trying to implement a basic live search bar so I have an event listening to any keyup:

```
'keyup input.search-query': function (evt) {
    Session.set("search-query", evt.currentTarget.value);
},
```

This seems to be working, except anytime I press a key, the search field is blurred so the second letter I type isnt in the text field! Any ideas how to prevent this from happening?

Edit:

Some more information:

```
Template.search.events({
    'keyup input.search-query': function (evt) {
        Session.set("search-query", evt.currentTarget.value);
    }, 
})

Template.search.searchResults = function () {
    var keyword  = Session.get("search-query");
    var query = new RegExp( keyword, 'i' );
    var results = Articles.find( { $or: [{'user': query},
                                        {'title': query},
                                        {'articleText': query},
                                        {'datetime': query}] } );
    return {results: results};
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was in the HTML actually.

I has the search bar and the search results in the same template, so whenever the template would refresh with new results, it would blur the search bar. All I did was make the search results its own template and import that template below the search bar so everything looks the same.

Comment: can you provide a more complete answer, like what did the resulting code look like?