# Live search in Meteor

Tags: html, meteor

I'm trying to create a live search feature with meteor similar to the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18436313/how-to-implement-a-live-search-in-meteor-without-text-input-blurring-after-every).

I have a simple Mongo collection called "people" with 4 fields - name, gender, email, phone.

Here is my html:

```html
<head>
  <title>People Search</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    {{> search}}
  </div>
</body>


<template name="search">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="search-query">Search:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control search-query" id="search-query">
  </div>
  <h1>People</h1>
  {{> people}}
</template>

<template name = "people">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {{#each searchresults.results}}
      <tr>
        <td>{{name}}</td>
        <td>{{gender}}</td>
        <td>{{email}}</td>
        <td>{{phone}}</td>
      </tr>
      {{/each}}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</template>
```

Here is my js file:

```js
People = new Mongo.Collection("people");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.search.events({
    'keyup input.search-query': function (evt) {
      Session.set("search-query", evt.currentTarget.value);
    },
  })

  Template.people.searchResults = function () {
    var keyword  = Session.get("search-query");
    var query = new RegExp( keyword, 'i' );
    var results = People.find( { $or: [{'name': query},
      {'gender': query},
      {'email': query},
      {'phone': query}] } );
    return {results: results};
  }
}
```

What should happen is on the event of text change in the text box, the collection is queried, and the results displayed in the table.
The event gets triggered, but the table does not get updated.

Thanks

Comment: what doesn't work? what do you expect to see happening and what do you see instead? what have done to instrument your code and which part still works as expected? what doesn't get executed? ... thanks for showing code, but please clarify a bit more the problem itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
{{#each searchresults.results}}
```

to

```
{{#each searchResults.results}}
```